# How to kill an heroku build that is in progress?

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

I accidentally pushed a build that does an npm install in the postinstall script. This has led to my heroku app being stuck in an infinite install loop. I searched the heroku documentation on how to kill builds but came up blank. The closest thing I found was https://help.heroku.com/Z44Q4WW4/how-do-i-stop-a-release-phase and I tried killing as per those instructions but my build won't die :(

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The [heroku-builds](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-builds#cancel-build) CLI plugin (`heroku plugins:install heroku-builds`) has a command which will stop a running build:

```
$ heroku builds:cancel -a your-app-name
```

All builds will time out too after a time that can go between 15 minutes to 1 hour.

Comment: this workd but one needs to `heroku plugins:install heroku-builds` before, just like explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56892546/299774

Comment: what if app is a review app?

Comment: Review apps are apps like any other, with their app name being the part of the hostname before `.herokuapp.com`. So you can kill them exactly the same way.

Answer (score 97):

If you have a build going into production right now and need to stop it quickly:

```
heroku plugins:install heroku-builds
heroku builds:cancel -a YOUR_HEROKU_APP_NAME
```

Comment: Perfect - I needed that quick cancel!

Comment: This is so amazing! fast and clean.

Comment: Once you are logged in, just `heroku builds:cancel` should do it - for the most recent ‍♂️ `build` at least.

Answer (score 39):

To view all builds run the following in your terminal:

`heroku builds -a YOUR_APP_NAME`

To cancel a specific (pending) build:

`heroku builds:cancel -a YOUR_APP_NAME HEROKU_BUILD_ID`

Update (4th July 2020):

If you see the message `Warning: builds is not a heroku command`, run `heroku plugins:install heroku-builds` and try again.

Comment: Arguably the best answer since it lets you cancel a specific build