# Heroku hanging: not releasing CLI after command

Tags: heroku, terminal, command-line-interface

This morning, for some reason when I run a command line such as 'heroku run worker' from the CLI, the CLI does not exit and instead it just hangs. CMD^c does not work and the only way to exit is to close the CLI window and open an new one.

It does not hang when I run heroku git commands, only after running heroku run. Other heroku commands also seem to work

Does anyone know why this might be happening?  I'm on a Mac running High Sierra

Answer (score 0):

```
heroku plugins:install heroku-builds
heroku builds:cancel -a YOUR_HEROKU_APP_NAME
```

[How to kill an heroku build that is in progress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50970807/how-to-kill-an-heroku-build-that-is-in-progress)